# Reopening a GTK & matplotlib window - GTK window is blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

My program (developed with `GTK` using `glade`) receives some data and has the option to display a seperate window containing a `matplotlib scatterplot` that represents the data.

**My problem is that if the user closes the graph `window` and reopens it, no graph is displayed. It is just a blank `GTK Window`.** I'm sure there is a simple fix, but there aren't many resources available that are relevant to my issue (or `GTK` and `matlplotlib` integration for that matter).

I have created a `Module` for my `scatterplot` so I can easily reuse it. I am just trying to get it to work, so the code isn't structured perfectly.

```
##Scatterplot Module:

import gtk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class ScatterPlot:
    def __init__(self):
       self.window = gtk.Window()
       self.window.connect("destroy", lambda x: self.destroy())
       self.window.set_default_size(500,400)
       self.is_hidden = False

       self.figure = Figure(figsize = (5,4), dpi=100)
       self.ax = self.figure
       self.ax = self.ax.add_subplot(111)
       self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
       self.window.add(self.canvas)

       self.Xs = list()
       self.Ys = list()

   def set_axis(self, xLimit = (0,384) , yLimit = (0,100)):
       self.ax.set_xlim(xLimit)
       self.ax.set_ylim(yLimit)

   def plot(self, xs, ys):
       self.Xs.extend([xs])
       self.Ys.extend([ys])
       self.ax.plot(xs,ys,'bo')

   def update(self):
       self.window.add(self.canvas)

   def set_title(self, title):
       self.ax.set_title(title)

   def show(self):
       self.window.show_all()
       self.is_hidden = False

   def hide(self):
       self.window.hide()
       self.is_hidden = True

   def destroy(self):
       self.window.destroy()
```

I call the module like so:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scatterplot = scatterplot.ScatterPlot()

        #When the user presses the "Graph" button it calls the following function
    def graph():
        self.scatterplot.plot(someDataX, someDataY)
        self.scatterplot.set_axis()
        self.scatterplot.set_title("Some Title")
        self.scatterplot.show()
```

(This was just an example of what my code looks like.)

When the `scatterplot` is closed, I am calling `self.window.destroy` instead of `self.window.hide`. When reopening is attempted, I call the same `graph()` function but, as stated above, the `GTK Window` does not display the graph. (When I first open it, it displays perfectly)

**My speculations:**

- Should I be calling `.hide()` instead of `.destroy()`?
- Is there a piece of code in `scatterplot`'s constructor that needs to be called again to create the `plot`?
- Or should I just re-instantiate the `plot` every time `graph()` is called?

Comment: `.hide()` keeps the data in memory - this is a good idea if you want to be able to show it again. Did you try it?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem. I have a feeling it's because it isn't redrawing (or re-showing) the plot, or the `GTK Drawing Area` that the plot is displayed in.

Comment: How does the user "close" the window - and how is it re-opened / what function is called after that happens. A .show() call probably is needed.

Comment: The user can only close the window by hitting the top right 'X'. When the graph is reopened, it calls the same `graph()` function above. The function does contain a `.show()` call. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the window is X'd, then I don't think you have any option but to re-instantiate. You might consider giving the window your "own" close button (rather than let the OS handle it) - display it in a window without title bar, ... But frankly I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: @Floris I moved two lines of code (as shown in my answer below) and was able to get the plot to reopen as well. Do you see any issues with what I have done below? Thanks again for your help Floris. I wish I would have solved that before taking the time to create this question...

Comment: The window gets destroyed per default if you click on the `X`. If you want to change this you have to [return True from the `delete-event` handler](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq10.006.htp). In this case you can really hiding instead of destroying it.

Comment: In the case you hide your window you should clear the axes before you plot a second time with [`Axes.cla`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.cla)

Comment: @JordanCarroll Then please update your answer so others can benefit from it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My Solution:

From:

```
class ScatterPlot:
    def __init__(self):
        #remove the following two lines
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.window.add(self.canvas)
```

Move the two lines of code to `show()`

```
def show(self):
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    self.window.add(self.canvas)
    self.window.show_all()
    self.is_hidden = False
```

Moving these two lines of code allows the graph to be displayed when re-opening the window.

Sidenote: Calling both `.destroy()` or `.show()` when closing the window will work. I'm not sure which one is better though.

Comment: Figuring it out by yourself, and then posting the answer, is a Best Practice - +1 for that! Now all you have to do is "accept" your own answer.

Comment: I will accept it in two days per restrictions from SO. Thanks.